# Placing Google Map dynamically

Tags: php, google-maps

I am developing a hotel reservation website, and I want to have a map section in every hotel that is listed. My problem is when every time I embed the code in to a form, I use to insert each hotel I have to escape the `"` quotation with a back space, `\`, for every map [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator) that I get from Google. The user of this site do not have the knowledge to do all this, so what is the other option to go about? How can I just embed this code with our any alteration?

An example is as follows.

```
$map = "<iframe width=\"200\" height=\"200\" frameborder=\"0\" scrolling=\"no\" marginheight=\"0\" marginwidth=\"0\" src=\"https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=L8&amp;aq=&amp;sll=12.039321,-76.113281&amp;sspn=132.79415,332.753906&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=Liverpool+L8,+United+Kingdom&amp;t=m&amp;z=14&amp;ll=53.389112,-2.95934&amp;output=embed\"></iframe><br /><small><a href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=embed&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=L8&amp;aq=&amp;sll=12.039321,-76.113281&amp;sspn=132.79415,332.753906&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=Liverpool+L8,+United+Kingdom&amp;t=m&amp;z=14&amp;ll=53.389112,-2.95934\" style=\"color:#0000FF;text-align:left\">View Larger Map</a></small>";
```

Comment: You have a form where users submit Google Maps embeddable code? You can just escape the input using [addslashes()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php) or something similar.

Comment: So the user provides to code for the page. Sounds like an XSS attack is imminent. Even if it is from people you trust (admins) you should still validate input. Who knows, someone might get drunk and kill your site.

Answer (score 0):

On the [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP) side of your form, use `addSlashes(...);` to add the slashes in there.